# Erro de listagem em sistema de busca com paginação

Tags: php, mysql, html5, banco-de-dados, lógica

Quando faço a consulta obtenho o seguinte resultado [imagem1]

Ao clicar para ir para página 2, obtenho o seguinte resultado [imagem2]

Ou seja, na página "1" tudo funcionando com o total de resultados exibidos (10) e com os total de links (2), só que ao ir para página "2", aparece muito mais links, o que indica que ele consultou e retornou toda tabela, preencheu com a quantidade respectiva de links e mostrou o conteúdo errado na página 2.

Obs:

19 campos com o termo CONFEF;
10 resultados por paginação;
4 links para página anterior e seguinte;
77 campos na tabela duvidas;

[image: imagem1]

[image: imagem2]

formulario.php

```html
<body>
     
        <form name="frmBusca" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="pesquisa.php?pag=1" >
            <input type="text" name="palavra" />
            <input type="submit"  value="Buscar" />
        </form>
     
    </body>
```

pesquisa.php

```js
<!-- Inicio do Sistema de Busca Interna -->
     
    <?php 
     
    //Se pg não existe atribui 1 a variável pag
    $pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? (int)$_GET['pag'] : 1 ;
     
    if($pag=='0'){
    $pag = '1';
    }
     
    // Pegamos a palavra
    $palavra = trim($_POST['palavra']);
     
    $maximo = '10';
     
    //Atribui a variável inicio o inicio de onde os registros vão ser mostrados por página, exemplo 0 à 10, 11 à 20 e assim por diante
    $inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo;
     
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM duvidas WHERE resposta LIKE '%$palavra%' LIMIT ".$inicio. ", ". $maximo;
     
    try {
    $consulta = $conecta->prepare($sql); 
    $consulta->execute();
      $conecta->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     
    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();// Recuperar todos valores encontrados
    $count = $consulta->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);// Quantos registros foram encontrados
    }catch (PDOException $erro) {
      die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados :" . $erro->getMessage());
    }
     
    if ($count != 0) {
    foreach($resultado as $res){
    $pergunta  = $res['pergunta'];
    $id = $res['id'];
     
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<a href="http://exemplo.com.br/visualizar_resposta.php?id='.$id.'">&bull; <span style="color:black; font-size:10px;">'.$pergunta.'</span></strong>';
    echo '<br>';
    }
     
    //echo "Foram encontrados ".$count." registro(s)";
    }
    // Se não houver registros
    else {
    echo "Nenhum produto foi encontrado com a palavra ".$palavra."";
    }
     
    ?>
     
    <!-- Fim Sistema de Busca Interna -->
     
    <!-- Inicio Paginação -->
     
     <?php
    // Query de consulta
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM duvidas WHERE resposta LIKE '%$palavra%'";
     
      try {
    $consulta = $conecta->prepare($sql); 
    $consulta->execute();
      $conecta->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     
    $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();// Recuperar todos valores encontrados
    $count = $consulta->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);// Quantos registros foram encontrados
    }catch (PDOException $erro) {
      die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados :" . $erro->getMessage());
    }
    $paginas = ceil($count/$maximo);
    $links = '4';
     
    echo '</br></br></br><ul id="paginacao">'; 
     
    echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag=1" >Primeira</a></li>';
     
    for($i = $pag-$links; $i <= $pag-1; $i++){
    if($i <= 0){
    }else{
    echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    }
     
    echo "<li>$pag</li>";
     
    for($i = $pag+1; $i <= $pag+$links; $i++){
    if($i > $paginas){
     
    }else{
    echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    }        
         echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag='.$paginas.'">Última</a></li></br></br></br>';
    echo'</ul>';
     
     
    ?>
     
    <!-- Fim Paginação -->
```

Comment: Olá, se a resposta abaixo não for suficiente, experimenta incorporar isto [Paginação com PHP + MySQLi - Completo & Explicado](https://youtu.be/zX0RK5EMHrM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Inicio do Sistema de Busca Interna -->

<?php 

    $pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? (int)$_GET['pag'] : 1; //Se 'pag' não está DEFINIDA, 'pag' recebe o valor '1'

    $maximo = '10'; // Quantidade máxima de regisros por página
    // Atribui à variável inicio, a partir de qual registro os resultados deverão ser exibidos. Exemplo: 0 à 10, 11 à 20 e assim por diante
    $inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo;

    // Pegamos a palavra
    if(isset($_POST['palavra'])){
        $palavra = trim($_POST['palavra']);
    }else{
        $palavra = trim($_GET['palavra']);
    }

    if($palavra != NULL){
        // Retorna apenas os registros PARECIDOS com 'palavra', limitando à 10 registros por página
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM duvidas WHERE resposta LIKE '%$palavra%' LIMIT $inicio, $maximo";
    }else{
        // Retorna todos os registros do BD
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM duvidas ORDER BY id LIMIT $inicio, $maximo";
    }

    try {
        $consulta = $conecta->prepare($sql); 
        $consulta->execute();
        $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
        //$count = $consulta->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Total de registros encontrados
    }catch (PDOException $erro) {
        echo "Erro ao selecionar: ".$erro->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if ($resultado) {
        foreach($resultado as $res){
            $pergunta   = $res['pergunta'];
            $id         = $res['id'];
            $resposta   = $res['resposta'];

            $texto_sem_tags = strip_tags($resposta);
            $texto_truncado = str_truncate($texto_sem_tags, 150, TRUE);
            $texto_destacado =  highlightkeyword($texto_truncado, $palavra);

            echo '<a href="http://cref14.org.br/visualizar_resposta.php?id='.$id.'"><strong><span style="color:black; font-size:10px;">'.$pergunta.'</span></strong></a>';
            echo'</br></br>';
            echo $texto_destacado;
            echo '<a href="http://cref14.org.br/visualizar_resposta.php?id='.$id.'"><strong style="color:#000;">    Continue lendo [...]</strong></a>';;
            echo'</br></br>';
        }
        //echo "Foram encontrados ".$count." registro(s).";
    }else{
        echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado com a palavra '".$palavra."'";
    }
?>

<!-- Fim Sistema de Busca Interna -->

<!-- Inicio Paginação -->

<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM duvidas WHERE resposta LIKE '%$palavra%'";

    try {
        $consulta = $conecta->prepare($sql); 
        $consulta->execute();
        //$resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
        $count = $consulta->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Total de registros encontrados
    }catch (PDOException $erro) {
        echo "Erro ao selecionar: ".$erro->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $paginas = ceil($count/$maximo);
    $links = '4';

    /* Primeira página */
    echo '</br></br></br><ul id="paginacao">';
    echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag=1&palavra='.$palavra.'" >Primeira</a></li>';
        for($i = $pag-$links; $i <= $pag-1; $i++){
            if($i <= 0){}
            else{
                echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag='.$i.'&palavra='.$palavra.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }

    /* Página atual */
    echo "<li>$pag</li>";

    /* Páginas restantes */
        for($i = $pag+1; $i <= $pag+$links; $i++){
            if($i > $paginas){}
            else{
                echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag='.$i.'&palavra='.$palavra.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }

    /* Última página */
    echo '<li><a href="pesquisa.php?pag='.$paginas.'&palavra='.$palavra.'">Última</a></li></br></br></br>';
    echo '</ul>';

?>

<!-- Fim Paginação -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se consegue enteder essas alterações!

```
<?php 
$pagina =  ($_GET['pagina'];?>
<h2><img src="imagens/apontar_paginas.png" alt="" width="12" /> <?php echo $pagina; ?></h2>

<?php 


$_GET['pag'] = (!isset($_GET['pag']))? 1 :$_GET['pag'];
$pag_ = $_GET['pag'];
    if($pag_ >= 1){
$pag = $pag_;
}else{
 $pag = 1;
}
$maximo = '15'; //RESULTADOS POR PÁGINA
$inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo;

$tabela = $_GET['pagina'];  
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM cdc_".$tabela." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo ") 
    or die(mysql_error());
      if(@mysql_num_rows($result) == '0'){
       echo "<br><font face=arial size=4px>OPS!, ESSA PÁGINA NÃO EXISTE! <br />";
}else{


?>

}
<?php 
 }
     $sql_res = mysql_query(" SELECT id FROM cdc_".$tabela." ");
    $total = mysql_num_rows($sql_res);

    $paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);
    $links = '5'; //QUANTIDADE DE LINKS NO PAGINATOR


    echo "<a href=\"index.php?cdc=ctrl&amp;pagina=".$tabela."&amp;pag=1\">Primeira Página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    for ($i = $pag-$links; $i <= $pag-1; $i++){
        if ($i <= 0){
        }else{
        echo"<a href=\"index.php?cdc=ctrl&amp;pagina=".$tabela."&amp;pag=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }
    echo "$pag &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    for($i = $pag +1; $i != $pag+$links; $i++){
        if($i > $paginas){
        }else{
        echo "<a href=\"index.php?cdc=ctrl&amp;pagina=".$tabela."&amp;pag=$paginas\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }
        echo "<a href=\"index.php?cdc=ctrl&amp;pagina=".$tabela."&amp;paginas=$paginas\">Última página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";


?>
```

Comment: o problema ainda persiste =\