# Paginação em SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma dúvida aqui, nem por questão de código, mas por questão de qual seria a lógica.

Possuo uma tabela com 6000 registros no MySQL. 
Tenho um script em PHP que retorna 50 registros por página, usando a função "LIMIT" do SQL.

Agora estou precisando buscar um único registro dessa tabela e saber em qual dessas "páginas" de 50 registros ele estará.

Por exemplo, se for o registro 68, eu preciso saber que ele está na 2ª página. Se for 120, na 3ª e assim por diante.

Isso é possível com o PHP ou com o MySQL? Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Obrigado.

Comment: Em que momento você precisa saber disso ?

Comment: @Zoom, é uma tabela com nicks e pontuações de jogadores, o jogador irá entrar no site, informar o nick, com base no nick irei buscar o ID e com base nesse ID eu preciso saber em página ele está. EDIT: A parte do ID está tranquilo, só estou quebrando a cabeça com essa questão da busca ai.

Comment: Entendi. Mas estranho você querer fazer isso. Você quer mostrar em que lugar ele está no ranking de pontuação ?

Comment: Exatamente @Zoom, eu poderia retornar facilmente só a posição dele com os dados e etc. Mas eu queria fazer desse modo descrito acima para que ele veja "ao redor" da posição dele.

Comment: Esse SELECT: `SELECT @NumRow := @NumRow + 1 As NumeroDaLinha, Nick, ID FROM Users, (SELECT @NumRow := 0) R ORDER BY Pontuacao` coloca uma coluna sequencial na sua consulta. Dessa forma você tem o número da posição do usuário. Agora tem que fazer a conta para saber em que página está esse usuário. Sou ruim de matemática.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84265/sistema-de-busca-com-pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o - Referente?

Comment: @Zoom, somos dois kkkk. Mas é justamente essa conta ai que eu não faço ideia de como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Bem se você está querendo descobrir apenas a página (supondo que você já saiba qual a posição o usuário/player se encontra), podes usar uma função matemática simples em PHP mesmo.

Por exemplo, se você está mostrando 50 resultados por página, é só fazer a posição do usuário/player divido por 50 e no caso arredondar o valor decimal para cima. 
Exemplo:

```
//posição do usuário
$pos = 68;
// isso ira gerar um decimal 1.36
$pag = $pos/50;

// o "ceil" irá arredondar para cima o decimal, no caso de 1.36 para 2
echo "Página: ".ceil($pag);
```

Para saber em qual página aparecerá outra posição é só alterar o valor em "$pos".
Outro exemplo:

```
//posição do usuário - Outra posição
$pos = 120;
// isso ira gerar um decimal 1.36
$pag = $pos/50;

// o "ceil" irá arredondar para cima o decimal, no caso de 2.4 para 3
echo "Página: ".ceil($pag);
```

Espero ter ajudado, acredito que isso resolva. Mas o mesmo pode ser feito também pelo SQL utilizando a função ROUND.

Att;